# Apache Flink: How to remove duplicates within select query?

Tags: sql, apache-flink, flink-sql

How to remove duplicates within a `SELECT` query using Apache fFlink?

My table is:
[image]

and I want to remove duplicates in ID with respect to keeping maximum in range

Comment: Are you running the query on static data set or on a data stream?

Comment: running on a static dataSet. @FabianHueske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the query is run on a static data set, it can be solved with regular SQL. Since Flink implements standard SQL, this query is not Flink-specific but would run on any relational database system.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.name, t.range 
  FROM t, (SELECT id, MAX(range) AS maxRange FROM t GROUP BY id) s
  WHERE t.id = s.id AND t.range = s.maxRange
```

Note that you will lose duplicates if there is an id for which there are more than one row with the maximum range.